# How to detect what mob hit a player 1.12

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making horror map. And i got some problems.

I need that when a player takes damage from a specific mob, a block is placed.
This block will start another system.
For example: if player have damage from zombie, iron block placing in some place. If player have damage from skeleton, redstone block placing in some place.
I hope you help me. And sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I would recommend updating to 1.14, as the commands have changed and help will be hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with advancements. You can have an advancement trigger of type [`entity_hurt_player`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Advancements/List_of_triggers#minecraft:entity_hurt_player) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Advancements/List_of_triggers&oldid=1438667#minecraft:entity_hurt_player)) and in its `damage.source_entity.type` condition check for the entity type, like skeleton. The example given in the wiki even does this:

> 

{
"criteria": {
"example": {
"trigger": "minecraft:entity_hurt_player",
"conditions": {
"damage": {
"source_entity": {
"type": "skeleton",
"direct_entity": {
"type": "arrow"
}
},
"taken": {
"min": 4.0
}
}
}
}
}
}

Then you just need to use a function as reward that places a block, it will automatically be executed as the player and at the position of the player.