# What commands to use to make a zombie which after hitting the player will give the player the poison effect?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried the execute command but the effect was that when I hit the zombie I was wearing a poison effect...

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Advancements/JSON_format#minecraft:entity_hurt_player

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect what mob hit a player 1.12](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/358843/how-to-detect-what-mob-hit-a-player-1-12)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something that while *technically* doesn't give the player poison on hit, gives it when they are standing so close to it that they would be hit.

```
execute at @e[type=minecraft:zombie,name="My Name, or something else to distinguish me"] run effect give @p[r=...35] poison 30 0
```

Comment: Only down side is that it would "go trough" shields I guess.

Answer (score -2):

```
/summon zombie ~ ~1 ~ {HandItems:[{Count:1,id:golden_sword,tag:{display:{Name:"\"Lucian\""},Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:1}]}},{}],HandDropChances:[1.0f,0.0f],ActiveEffects:[{Id:19,Amplifier:0,Duration:999999}]}
```

Comment: I did not mean that. In your command, you summoned a zombie with a poison effect. I meant that the zombies would give the player an effect when the zombies hit him.